# SuiteScript 2 log email sent to transaction

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have an email campaign app that I am writing and they need the log of the email attached to the transaction record, to show up in the communications tab on the transactions record. I have added the necessary parameters to send email, {transactionId:11111} and it doesn't throw an error but doesn't log the email. I have no idea what could be wrong, the email is sent fine just no record added to communications. An assist would be awesome, I am in a time constraint, thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a subset of the SS2.0 code that I use to send an invoice email ad attach that email to the invoice record itself.  The relevant part is setting the `transactionID` property on an object in the `relatedRecords` property.

```js
function getInvoicePdf() {
    var transactionId = record.id;
    return render.transaction({
        entityId: transactionId,
        printMode: 'PDF'
    });
}

function getRenderedEmailTemplate() {
    var EMAIL_TEMPLATE = 32;
    return render.mergeEmail({
        templateId: EMAIL_TEMPLATE,
        transactionId: record.id
    });
}

function sendEmail() {
    var AR_EMPLOYEE = 420340;
    email.send({
        author: AR_EMPLOYEE,
        recipients: addresses.to,
        cc: addresses.cc,
        subject: 'TESTING - ' + emailTemplate.subject,
        body: emailTemplate.body,
        attachments: [invoiceAttachment],
        relatedRecords: {
            transactionId: record.id
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Well at least it confirms I am on the right path, I am passing the transactionId value, it runs without error and generates the email but I don't see any record in the transaction. The only real difference is that I am not attaching the document to the email. Thanks very much it at least confirms by sanity, thanks again for your help

Comment: I did get it to work by jazzing around with ParseInt, but I can't still get the transaction record attached to certain emails. I am doing Opportunity, Sales Order, and Purchase Order. Opportunity doesn;t have a document but the other two do, if anyone has an idea please chime in, otherwise thanks for the help, I am farther than I was. :)